# SQL Calculate the rate of growth of the indicator over time

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a postgres table like this:

| dates date | name text | values real |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-05-01 | A | 1 |
| 2017-05-02 | A | 3 |
| 2017-05-02 | B | 10 |
| 2017-05-03 | A | 6 |
| 2017-05-04 | A | 12 |
| 2017-05-03 | B | 10 |
| 2017-05-04 | B | 10 |
| 2017-05-05 | B | 11 |

how can I calculate the rate of growth of the indicator over time with SQL, and get the following table

| dates date | name text | values real | growth real |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-05-01 | A | 1 | NULL |
| 2017-05-02 | A | 3 | 2 |
| 2017-05-02 | B | 10 | NULL |
| 2017-05-03 | A | 6 | 3 |
| 2017-05-04 | A | 12 | 6 |
| 2017-05-03 | B | 10 | 0 |
| 2017-05-04 | B | 10 | 0 |
| 2017-05-05 | B | 11 | 1 |

Examle for A:
2017-05-01 (1) 
2017-05-02 (3 ) 
2017-05-03 (6) 
2017-05-04 (12) 
I am calculating the difference in metric between adjacent dates And got the follow 
2017-05-01 (NULL) 
2017-05-02 (3-1 =2) 
2017-05-03 (6-3 = 3) 
2017-05-04 (12-6=6)

Comment: Please explain your output. How it will be calculated?

Comment: @AkhileshMishra, i ll show using A: 2017-05-01 A 1
2017-05-01 (1)
2017-05-02 (3 )
2017-05-03 (6)
2017-05-04      (12)
I am calculating the difference in metric between adjacent dates
And got the follow
2017-05-01 (NULL)
2017-05-02 (2)
2017-05-03 (3)
2017-05-04      (6)

Comment: Please write the explanation in the question by editing it.

Comment: Added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` window function here if your table is having previous dates without gap:

Try this:

```
select 
*, 
values-(lag(values) over(partition by name order by dates)) "growth" 
from test
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=62f88bbf042ff737cf54f24e26a3ea19)